# javascript timers and highscore

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i would like to use a stop watch to time a users interaction on my html page. Once they click the stop button i want to record their high score time and replace the high score every time a better time happens. i have my stop watch working, but not sure how to figure out the high score part.

my code for html is:

```
     <body>
  <fieldset>
            <legend>Stop Watch</legend>
            <input type="button" id="start" value="Start">
            <input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop">
            <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset">
            <span id="s_minutes">00</span>:
            <span id="s_seconds">00</span>:
            <span id="s_ms">000</span>
            <span id = "highscore"></span>
        </fieldset> 


parts of my javascript code is here:

"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var stopwatchTimer;
var elapsed = { minutes:0, seconds:0, milliseconds:0 }; 


     var padSingleDigit = function(num) {
            return (num < 10) ? "0" + num : num;
        };

        var tickStopwatch = function() {    
            // increment milliseconds by 10 milliseconds
            elapsed.milliseconds = elapsed.milliseconds + 10;

            // if milliseconds total 1000, increment seconds by one and reset milliseconds to zero
            if (elapsed.milliseconds === 1000) {
                elapsed.seconds++;
                elapsed.milliseconds = 0;
            }
            // if seconds total 60, increment minutes by one and reset seconds to zero
            if (elapsed.seconds === 60) {
                elapsed.minutes++;
                elapsed.seconds = 0;
            }

            //display new stopwatch time
            $("s_minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(elapsed.minutes);
            $("s_seconds").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(elapsed.seconds);
            $("s_ms").firstChild.nodeValue = elapsed.milliseconds;
        };

        // event handler functions
        var startStopwatch = function() {  

            tickStopwatch();
            stopwatchTimer = setInterval(tickStopwatch, 10);
        };

        var stopStopwatch = function() {
            // stop timer
            clearInterval(stopwatchTimer);
            var score ;
            var highscore=0;
           score = getTime();

            if (score>highscore){

            highscore== score;
            }
            $("highscore").firstChild.nodeValue = highscore;

        };

        var resetStopwatch = function() {
            // stop timer
            clearInterval(stopwatchTimer);

            // clear elapsed object and stopwatch display
            elapsed = { minutes:0, seconds:0, milliseconds:0 }; 

            $("s_minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = "00";
            $("s_seconds").firstChild.nodeValue = "00";
            $("s_ms").firstChild.nodeValue = "000";
        };

        window.onload = function() {


            $("start").onclick = startStopwatch;
            $("stop").onclick = stopStopwatch;
            $("reset").onclick = resetStopwatch;
        };
```

Comment: Without server-side or database this case seems to be impossible, even if you would like to make change at source code on client-side, there's no way to update it at the server without right resources.

Comment: You could make use of cookies which lets you store something in the users browser, but if they were to either use a different browser or clear their cache then the time would be reset. As @JakubChlebowicz said, without a server side there isn't much to be done that will definitely work at all times (at least that I know of).

Comment: so i need to add php into the code then?